# How to make NetBeans use C++14 when it performs syntax checking?

Tags: c++, netbeans, c++14

While setting all the building options in NetBeans to C++ 14 makes it to use C++ 14 to build the project, it still uses C++ 98 for syntax checking (all `auto` types are marked as errors, new functions in C++ 11/14 are marked as unrecognized as well). How can I make NetBeans to use C++ 14 for syntax checking?

Comment: What are OS/ToolChain/NetBeans version numbers?

Comment: @HEKTO MacOS clang and NetBean 8.2.

Comment: I don't develop in MacOS, but - right-click on the project name, then hit the button `Code Assistance -> Reparse Project` - it often helps me in this situation

Comment: @HEKTO It unfortunately does not help me. Thank you any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to:
Tools > Options > C/C++ > Code Assistance tab > select relevant tool collection > C++ Compiler tab > Macro Definitions list

In that list there should be a definition for *__cplusplus*. Change the value to *__cplusplus=201402L* or whichever version you need. You may then need to right click on the project and use the Code Assistance > Reparse Project option.

Be aware it will occasionally add the default definition back in. I'm not sure what causes it but it's worth double checking in case of future issues.

Valid for at least v8.0.2